# Need to child div to become parent but is it possible in js or css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, positioning

Hi I need to move a child element to become a parent, so for example i have this code:

```
<div id="parent1"></div>

<div id="parent2">
<div id="child1">some text in here</div>
</div>
```

i want child1 to be moved outside of parent2 for example under parent 1 so its like:

```
<div id="parent1"></div>
<div id="child1">some text in here</div>

<div id="parent2">

</div>
```

I cannot edit the page source code to alter it so need to do it in jquery or css, any ideas anyone.

thanks

Comment: You are not making the child `Element` a parent `Element` in your example (it already is a parent to its text `Node`) . You are simply moving it to another position in the `Document`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#child1').insertAfter('#parent1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the DOM using CSS, you can only change how it looks. A jQuery answer has been given, in plain js:

```
var p = document.getElementById('parent1');
var c = document.getElementById('child1');

if (p && c) {
  // insert c as last child of p
  p.appendChild(c);

  // insert c as first child of p
  p.insertBefore(c, p.firstChild);
}
```

If you want the first option, you can do it as one line but I don't recommend it:

```
document.getElementById('parent1').appendChild(document.getElementById('child1'));
```

If you alias the DOM methods, it can be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#child1').insertBefore('#parent2');
```

Answer (score -1):

you have multiple choices to do this, some of them are fallowing-

```
$('#parent1').prepend($('#child1'));
$('#child1').prependTo($('#parent1'));
 $('#child1').insertAfter($('#parent1'));
```

**fiddle**:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RLAAQ/)

Comment: **-1** - none of those options do what was asked for

Comment: are you mad or something else..have you not seen the demo..go up and see what OP has marked as a answer..same thing which i have written in my answer

Comment: Ok, so I misread the last one. However, the other two and the demo are wrong. They put `#child1` inside `#parent1`. That's not what was asked for.